# Miniaturizing home automation help? [Novice]

Tags: arduino, wifi, home-automation

Right now I am doing a home automation project and I want to create **two** things. The **first** is a device that looks like [this](http://www.belkin.com/conserve/socket/) but has the capability to also be controlled over wifi using Arduino. I know the Arduino route, but the final product is clunky. [This](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10747) device is really big and I was wondering how I could make it smaller using relays. Is there another device that I could use?

The **second** project is to replace and old wall socket with a newer one that has **2 USB ports and 2 outlets** that could be controlled through Wifi communication. I am lost here. I understand how an outlet works with the 3 wires, but how would I be able to create a system that can take the command ("on/off").

Can I use the belkin WeMo to learn more? Any help at all will be great.

Comment: This should be two questions.

Comment: Yes, please submit a second question to split this into two.

Answer (score 1):

Miniturisation, mains and novice status don't go well together. I'd look harder for existing products, such as http://rayshobby.net/blog/?p=936 : in that case you're modifying the battery-powered radio remote, and leaving the radio-controlled switched mains units sealed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mechanical relay driven by a simple Transistor or you take a thyristors based AC-Switch (as example http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM144) The advantage of the electronic AC-Switches is that they consume less power, are smaller and less susceptible to errors.
But whatever you do: Be careful. Working with 230VAC can be dangerous if handled wrong.

Comment: Have a look at Application Note AN392 ([http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEMQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fweb%2Fen%2Fresource%2Ftechnical%2Fdocument%2Fapplication_note%2FCD00003820.pdf&ei=rntgVM-8KIjfONC0gOgI&usg=AFQjCNEgGvNJDVfEIpYxntmkt6Oynfil_w&sig2=5RtNf9kg8-Lhswr4rp9OMg&bvm=bv.79189006,d.ZWU]) for an example schematic.